# Evaluate $\int_0^1\int_y^\sqrt{y}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Not sure how to simplify this and start working it out. Any help and step through would be much appreciated thanks!

Ive gotten to $$\left[\frac{1}{2}y(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}x^3\right]^\sqrt{y}_y$$

Is this step right? And how do I carry on from here?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you change the limits and order of integration and convert it to its equivalent form $dy\, dx$? I guess, that'll make things easier.

Comment: set $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\int_0^1\int_y^\sqrt{y}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy=\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{x}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dydx=\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)_{x^2}^{x}dx$$ also $$\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)_{x^2}^{x}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\int_0^1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$ now let $t=x^2+1$. From here you can do

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\int_0^1 x\sqrt{x^2+1}$?

Comment: @Dear  Swapnil Tripathi, yes thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$\int_0^1\int_y^\sqrt{y}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{x}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dy\,dx$$

then set $u=x^2+y^2$.